# Idea for a better AR image tracking, by enhancing the trackable object/surface with IR lighting

Tags: augmented-reality, arkit, arcore, lighting, infrared

I am working on a AR project, where a space fixed position poster would be augmented, in a indoor space, but light may vary and poster (that cannot change) is not rated as good as wanted.

In a brainstorm trying to fix this issue, I came up with the idea of
infrared projection light lines or shapes on the poster, or hide behind the poster small IR LEDs emitting infrared light through small halls on the poster, creating a pattern.

And somehow, with the above methods, try to track IR light paterns instead of the poster.

Is this thing doable with current ARKit or ARCore solutions?

Because it was doable with Computer Vision frameworks, 10 years ago, but with big latency and middle tracking results.

Any thoughts and ideas on this?

Answer (score 1):

### About IR LEDs

An idea of ARKit's tracking with a help of Infrared LEDs is cool but you can't adequately implement it. ARKit uses IR-technology only with TrueDepth camera, because it has corresponding sensors (dot projector and infrared camera – 30K dots). But all iPhone and iPad rear cameras can't see any IR light because, as I know, ***Apple added an IR-filter*** over the lens that blocks out infrared light, so the IR light cannot be seen on the iPhone's screen. ***You can test it using IR remote control for TV***.

### ARKit 4.0

The most practical solution for robust tracking in ARKit is to use a LiDAR scanner what you can find inside fourth generation of iPad Pro 2020. LiDARs allow you to track a surrounding environment with very poor lighting conditions and with no feature points at all. LiDAR instantly builds a mesh (at nanoseconds speed) based on topology of real world objects in your room and applies to that mesh a preconfigured occlusion material.

However, ARKit image detection feature doesn't depend on LiDAR scanners. It entirely depends on RGB cameras and computer vision algorithms. So, the only possible solution in this case is to properly light a tracked image.

### ARCore 1.18

At the moment in the latest version of ARCore there's a support for ToF sensors to very quickly track surrounding environment (almost the same way as it's in ARKit 4.0). It became possible after implementing a Depth API. But in your case, as in the previous example, this is also a useless feature.

I should say that some Android phones barely see IR light (these Android phones have IR blocking filters but these filters are not very high quality). However this will not help you in image tracking. Hence, the only robust solution in this case is to properly light a tracked image as well.